# progressive tense for completed actions

Tags: past-tense, continuous

This is based on a true story that happened many, many years ago in Scotland. One day Mr Clark **was walking** home with a smile on his face. He **was carrying** something very valuable in his hand: tickets for a long, long journey.

This is the beginning of a true story https://www.test-english.com/grammar-points/b1/past-simple-past-continuous-past-perfect/3/

What I don't understand is the use of progressive tenses in this little paragraph. For me both actions will be completed, nothing arrived when he was walking and carrying and it is not said that both actions (carrying and walking ) are happening now, only one day . In fact I understand that both actions are the background of the story and that they are happening now so progressive tense is needed but that seems strange  because one day does not mean now for me

Answer (score 3):

By convention English narrative almost always uses the **past tense**.  While the story is about something that has *completed*, the story itself is being told in the moment, and so we think of it as *ongoing action*.

> Mary **was making** breakfast when the spaceship **landed** in her backyard.  "That's odd," she **thought**. "You would expect aliens from another planet to be more considerate of one's azaleas."

Actions that would normally take the simple present are "backshifted" to the simple past. Continuous (or concurrent) actions that would take the present continuous are shifted to the past continuous.

Dialog, however, is not usually *backshifted*, and there are various other conventions for things like direct narration, which often uses the present tense as a way to speak directly to the reader.